# Administration: How often, if ever, should farm services be "restarted"?

Tags: 2007, restart

Looking for some advice. We have a small internal 2007 farm with a potential user base of 400 although active users is much smaller. About 10 sites each with many sub sites. We run a weekly "shutdown" script that restarts the services and IIS. However one night the sp farm never came back up as one of the sites exceeded the 90 second shutdown timeout.

So now the question is, do we really need to have a scheduled "restart" to free up runaway processes or memory leaks? I know it was an issue in the past but what is the best practices in this regard? In terms of 24x7 availability should we cease this restart script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So now the question is, do we really need to have a scheduled
>   "restart" to free up runaway processes or memory leaks?

Nope you don't need to restart your server just to free up runaway processes or memory leaks.

Recycling Application pool should do it for you. You might want to read this blog post,

```
[Set application pool recycling settings for better availability SharePoint Server 2007][1]
```

**Personal Experience**

I got one SharePoint 2007 server on Windows Server 2003 OS for last 1.5 years and it only required couple of times to be restarted even that not because of memory leaks (its a development server).

We don't restart our production or staging servers either which are being used by 2000+ users. Application pool recycling at 4am is about right with a warm up timer job runs each hour to warm up root Site collections.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the 2007 systems I worked with years ago benefited from scheduled service restarts, though I seem to remember this being less of an issue after SP2.  I would typically set the IIS Application Pool to recycle at a specified time.  It wasn't a full restart of the server or any services.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of what the Best Practice is on this but we physically restart all of our SharePoint farms during our weekly maintenance window because in the past we've lost days troubleshooting errors that disappeared after a restart.  Microsoft probably doesn't recommend it but I can tell you that it has helped us significantly.